# How to handle multiple windows in Python selenium with Firefox driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I want to learn  **WINDOW** handling in Python Selenium.

My Task is:

First open 'Google.com'.

Second open 'Yahoo.com' in **New Window**.

Third switch back to **First Window** and click on Gmail Link.

Fourth switch to **Second Window** and click on Finance Link.

Following Code works for me:

```
browser.get("http://www.google.co.in")
browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')")
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[0])
print(browser.title)
gmail=browser.find_element_by_class_name("gb_P")
gmail.click()
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1])
print(browser.title)
fin=browser.find_element_by_link_text("Finance")
fin.click()
```

But when I try to change sequence to task as:

First open 'Google.com'.

Second open 'Yahoo.com' in **New Window**.

Third **remaining in same window** and click on Finance Link.

Fourth switch to **First Window** and click on Gmail Link.

The below **altered code for the task** in which after opening yahoo.com in new window and then clicking on finance link and then switching to main window containing Google.com then clicking on Gmail link doesn't work:

```
browser.get("http://www.google.co.in")
browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')")
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1])
print(browser.title)
fin=browser.find_element_by_link_text("Finance")
fin.click()
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[0])
print(browser.title)
gmail=browser.find_element_by_class_name("gb_P")
gmail.click()
```

But if I **refresh** the page after switching to the **Yahoo** tab this works only in **Chrome**  Driver and not in **Firefox** Driver.

```
browser.get("http://www.google.co.in")
print(browser.current_window_handle)
browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')")
print(browser.current_window_handle)

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))


browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1])
print(browser.current_window_handle)
print(browser.title)

browser.refresh()

fin=browser.find_element_by_link_text("Finance")
fin.click()
print(browser.window_handles)

WebDriverWait(browser,10000)

browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[0])
print(browser.title)
print(browser.current_window_handle)
gmail=browser.find_element_by_class_name("gb_P")
gmail.click()
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the question to what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @DebanjanB why didn't that code for the altered sequence of my task didn't worked?

Comment: @DebanjanB why didn't the code for the altered sequence of the Task didn't worked?

Comment: Update the question with _what doesn't works_ as in `altered code for the task doesn't work`

Comment: @DebanjanB I have tried to explain in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

As per your updated question a few words about *Tab/Window switching/handling*:

- Always keep track of the *Parent Window* handle so you can traverse back for the rest of your usecases.
- Always use *WebDriverWait* with *expected-conditions* as [**`number_of_windows_to_be(num_windows)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.number_of_windows_to_be)
- Always keep track of the *Child Window* handles so you can traverse back if required.
- Here is your own code with some minor tweaks mentioned above:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  #other lines of code
  browser.get("http://www.google.co.in")
  print("Initial Page Title is : %s" %browser.title)
  windows_before  = browser.current_window_handle
  print("First Window Handle is : %s" %windows_before)
  browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')")
  WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  windows_after = browser.window_handles
  new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
  # browser.switch_to_window(new_window) <!---deprecated>
  browser.switch_to.window(new_window)
  print("Page Title after Tab Switching is : %s" %browser.title)
  print("Second Window Handle is : %s" %new_window)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Initial Page Title is : Google
  First Window Handle is : CDwindow-34D74AB1BB2F0A1A8B7426BF25B86F52
  Page Title after Tab Switching is : Yahoo
  Second Window Handle is : CDwindow-F3ABFEBE4907CFBB3CD09CEB75ED570E
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: TAB_SWITCH]

Now you have got both the *Window Handles* so you can easily switch to any of the *TABs* to perform any action.

Comment: Sir still I can't open **FINANCE** link on **YAHOO** first then switch back to **GOOGLE** and click on **GMAIL**.

Comment: it only works if I refresh the page after switching!!

Comment: @user8810517 This answer was constructed as per your question (heading) `How to handle multiple windows in Python` and `WINDOW handling in Python Selenium`. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question with you new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Sir your answer has definitely answered the main query. But half of my question remains unanswered. Why didn't my code work in altered sequence of my task. I have updated question with how refershing the page after switching works but that too only in Chrome Driver.