# How to make your code run even if error occurs using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

i want to run my code if error also occur.  Is is possible if error arises and i want to open my tab for these two errors and rest if no error let code run

```
        chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/ptiwar34/Documents/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities())

        myList = ['DYNJ58829','MDS806800','0409-6637-34H','SKA677256','PNAMDFC8V1PA','ORT23210XLDH','MMM82002G','ULCL500R','CRU911452','DYND80230AH','SYR103253','MDSM611505Z','AUG63700','DYNJ59758','MDS160664','KDL9780','NONLV200M','PTXMX9341L','ASO1C3305','ALI95904','NON24340','829NNTXS','QTXTX802322','SYR110020H','MMMV22285','MCKPC3787','PDC506514PDM','MMM1016Z','DYK1000TSE','B-D309629Z','B-D381434Z','DYNJ900988B','CLO30577','VS311M','NONSW400XL','5582CHRM','NON241280','K-C89051','NON27116XL','HMK5224R','DYKE1118','MSC5544','GHF131240','DYND140216','MMM15301Z','DYNJ01208H','MSC097063H','CVC610942','MPP200215Z','EXGTAT2000','MIL3010','MSCEDURULER','B-D305851Z','BRD0035380Z','BXTSEN73HNLS2','DYNJ60015','PSY6239P','CUR251272','DYNJ47278B','MSC3266H','BMGV460820','SGE7909H','WOL66083LW30','PTX305306Z','NPBMAXP','DYNJ41030F','SWD724500','RSH1000RH','DYNJ48852D','MMM1584S','ORT23220M','GOL51805','A70107006R','DYNJ902441C','DYNJAA10160','NODOD13111100','SGECT4004H','HCTHHG000','SKA961200BX','HUD522007','AND7802H','GEM1140S','NMGA1200H','DYKD100EPKLF1','PINK2503','MDS4431145','MDS251518LF','CUR253200','B-D377120','SYRS100255Z','MDS705153H','GRM170','COI11482','PDI21276724','ALA48970Z','PRG97073H','HTP79530','DYNJ904287','SQU025510CSH','M-A53110LF','MSC9505YDH','CND0031000H','MMM2345NHH','NON241286','SCS6883S','8832JNTM','ETHY344H','MDST0201','MMM15330ZZ','PTXER4009','NON28626','RSH124700010','NON270001S','IMP091005','NON255145','NONPBM800B','PTX4900','MBG1468P','EXGTAT5000','MDS1010225','BXTV11600300','ABO03P6401','K-C99285','CON59540000','MSC095206H','HUD122660','SQU064927','ETH1978CS','NON245276','ASO118103H','0009-3475-03','ESRK3002','ETHDNX12','DYNJ48589B','KDL1600','USUOMST10SB','NON26899','HHSPG','MCAN0050','DYND15203','MDSPTY2OZCN','MSG2580','DYNJP1060A','HTP11202','375544000RH','DYND300010','SWD660143H','MDS8086H','MDRQM1836SL6C','BMG4251709Z','KDL85131','DAY020537Z','NON25224','DYND70293H','ADC427','BXT65652567','UTD66000714Z','MDS046006','PCD082020','BXT001903AH','DYNJ902564D','CAM000105','MDS1299220','BMG418021','FG2603','HTP18392','COI11590','MNT416','MDS3248101','HMQ110706','MDT14WHT38TE','SDJ7984028','SYRS100187Z','B-D305195','WSD909165','K-C52818','MDS3230215','MDS80337Z','MDS4016104','HTP18132','SWD773621','W-A3942211100','MMO2328H','GEM2124T','DYNJ43441A','K-C34156','PTX005465','BXT2D72N85XZ','DYNJRA1022A','COI10567','AZRPFNBF1000','BHD766H','MRS653320Z','HTP18923','MPASR315','NON27200','PQDPM3600','ESRK2000','SWD431302Z','SYR110235Z','BMG473448','MDTPC4M34','DYNJAAHMEHEPA','MSL06545','SYR130010Z','MDS093944H','GEM1124T','CRI5000','NON02315H','DYNJ57651','COI11492','RSH18542028','PWF51170H','MSD02016','BHL2B2543Q','DYNJAPF6030','PAIN0930A','B-D305601','MDS093948','BXT2D72N75X','MDRQWRC18363G','BMGV1921','HDIA3H0181Z','PINK2504H','B-D367283Z','SYRS101272FZ','MPH01WMLWMT5','MIK07CA109','KDL67800H','ALA48565Z','COI1759','DELIVER1','GHF3857','MDS0817617','GPK80900','BMG333855','DYNJ35212F','NPKP03672H','ALA42180Z','K-CT17X5','J-J6823A','MSC86400','DYNJSD1061','DYND50422','SDJ7989071','DYNJ904195','BRD0165L20H','FITSTRETCHU1','UTD66800405Z','ARWAB05060PK','MNT6300H','MDS809850','B-D408269Z','PMP4173','B-D373807','WOL66081LW30','MSC3066H','HTP3812','MNT1012','J-J9082Z','BMG313004','FOGCTF03','SLDBL250','ABB1265828','HTP18112','BMGL7501','DYND40702F','B-D305763Z','MDS066003Z','MDS251512LF','NON21430LFH','MDS80615T','RCC12016','MDS1247614F','BMG4894278','0409-1159-01','PRD5787004CS','HTBH7658TW','MDS9914HP','K-C79725','ORT16300S','HTP18414','MDS087006LF','HUD1166Z','KDL2022AZ','NON22660','B-D305156Z','SCS307393','MDS400EL','PM2127-18','ASOLCC016','MDSP501100','MSC7322EPH','FIT33600AZ','BXT2D72N80XZ','SQU175611','SQU411807','MSG2085','PPR021002','DYND80417','DYNJAA9500','B-D305932ZZ','MSC5100H','NON27375','W-A03100U','ASOLCC012','QTX716510','SWD270207','MDS601MDBL','DYNJAAJRS3','MSC2712H','DYND10722','MSG9065H','ASO111987','COI11473','PTX580011H','B-D405092','MENMX5030','DVT10R','FG2702','DYNJ902990B','SCS7345850','MDTVCVF184854','SWD412600H','ABB1268928','BXTAT71021','KTC627503410','MDS806570','MDS4051203','MPH01WRJRA','DYNJ904282','MSC094109','DYNJAAPI100SH','SDJ7992170','ASO150377H','MIK03KP30','PRG74897','DYNJP2411','DYNJ56767','B-D309570','MMM73003','PBE1098','MMM15341Z','MMM1296F','B-D373911','MDS88000B6','NON25501H','RSH504570','K-C34198','DRE3241482A','ADLR305222','DB230','HUD111030','BXTLTSP1500','DYNJE63654S','DYNJ904472A','ETHZ493G','WTLSB2','QTX624','MDS9913HPLRE','MPP3003U','ASH4101440','MDTS2474V4E','MDTSB8B35MUL','DYND11218','SYR101272Z','NON80328Z','BXTDJ4011XH','KDL2835Z','DYNJ41039B','BMGS80045384H','MDS9961067','BRD0043600','DYND41904','AR6592083RH','COKG32789EA','M-A58201','49281-418-50','MMM90046','CUR02279RBZ','DYNJRA0349B','CUR253590H','MDS202105','DYNJS0115','NON27200XL','ORT11100XLCS','NON23326','ALA42311CS','MDS138020','MSG2480Z','MDS138007Z','0409-2339-34','MSG2010300','DYNJ24715K','8800JTHL','DYND74020','KDL8403H','BRD53614GH','BRD154004H','DYNJP2228P','BRD123624AH','MDS3265106','DYNJ37697C','CND0035040','B-D382523','DYND11502H','MSC281226LBH','MDS30408B','HUD809337','BCC902001','ALA1439','MMM76530','DYNJ24716F','MDSM611550','MPPA504U','MLK96370H','MPHT0001','ETHJ232H','COI10881','BMG413504H','GOJ90211M','HUD510215','MSC1044Z','DYND11573H','SQU413155','MDTFALLMATG','MSC351300H','ARNES01','NON28533BZ','NON27036','BVS376984','MDSMJ361','MDS89668XW','COI1166H','AED9730SMA','BMG470191','W-A106618','QTXAD300500','MSC9748H','DYNJ56530A','MSC9866EPZ','MCKC9108M','MF545H','DYNJP2205S','MSG9660','DERTP1105','MDSP105224','SWD1540111CS','MDS601LD','MMM15342Z','BHL2B1322Q','DYND74278','ASH4001440','MDSP121010','MDS5452015F','MMO1025','BHL2N3345','KCP41083','ENT1255BH','MSC281242LB','QTX251001','EVSTOOL121P','RDPA22','USU173049H','DYNJ51813A','MDS093902','849NNTM','MSC97162EPZ','MIT6P10755','DYNJ05144','DYNJ50952C','BHL2C4040','SDJ7990870','DYND70360','VS711S','CON6112','B-D305921Z','B-D305220Z','BRD153204H','SKA759508','DYNJ54594C','ADC352','COI50462H','MDS78912Z','BMG4253523Z','HMK10008','MSC0924004H','COI15606','PCD085005','PRD5787003CSZ','NON255015','GCT31433538','DYNJ43869F','B-D305195Z','J-J801407Z','MDS1228118','AUG63500','MLK86051H','DYND60605H','MNK0005','DYND20300','DET3PHTRODWM','NON27386','DYND70800','ETH1735G','BMGL5100','KDL8938FP','PAIN0545','MDS6802','K-C47500','MSG1580Z','ETHA185H','HUD1101','DYNJ902789A','CND130309AH','KDL441107H','LTP31142980','LTP31142493Z','MDS1186301','J-J801399Z','NON6028H','MND0103042734','SCP18020','BRD042824','W-A08800U','MSG5065H','610NCCM-CM','B-D306545Z','MSC20109EPH','MDS9910HPRE','ARWAK15703HH','PMP4173H','NON270201Z','MSG2065Z','SLT49507725','RTI10131H','MMM15382HH','HUN6030622','COKG14731EA','SKA967600','MMM90203','BRD50614H','375554000RH','HCS120E','DYNJ50743A','MCD114130C','B-D377210','MSC098214','W-A68064','MDS31505B']
        unspsc_link = []
        for i in myList:
            unspsc_link.append(f"https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP{i}")
        d.get('https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS705312'
   for my_href in unspsc_link:            
        windows_before  = d.current_window_handle
        d.execute_script("window.open('" + my_href +"');")
        WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2)) 
        windows_after = d.window_handles
        new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0] 
        d.switch_to.window(new_window) 
        time.sleep(3)
        print(d.title)
        d.close() 
        d.switch_to.window(windows_before)
```

i want to run my code for next value even if error arises like generally there two error arises and i want to open my tab for these two errors

```
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
      ValueError: No tables found
```

Comment: post error log with line number. You can have a check like `if obj: # do stuff on obj else: # goto next one`

Comment: At which step/line are you exactly stuck? What are your exact manual steps?

Comment: hey @DebanjanB actually some of the link in saved unspsc_link - list is not a valid web page so it stop over there then i have to remove these link from list then again i start from the new value from list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more details about your usecase interms of what you exactly mean by **exception arises** would have been helpful. However,  to iterate over all the links within the list and opening the urls in the adjacent tab if an element with `id` with `#element_css` isn't available, considering it as the exception, you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  myList = ['CAM000105','MDS1299220','BMG418021','FG2603','HTP18392','COI11590','MNT416','MDS3248101','HMQ110706','MDT14WHT38TE','SDJ7984028','SYRS100187Z','B-D305195','WSD909165','K-C52818','MDS3230215','MDS80337Z','MDS4016104','HTP18132','SWD773621','W-A3942211100','MMO2328H','GEM2124T','DYNJ43441A','K-C34156','PTX005465','BXT2D72N85XZ','DYNJRA1022A','COI10567','AZRPFNBF1000','BHD766H','MRS653320Z','HTP18923','MPASR315','NON27200','PQDPM3600','ESRK2000','SWD431302Z','SYR110235Z','BMG473448','MDTPC4M34','DYNJAAHMEHEPA','MSL06545','SYR130010Z','MDS093944H','GEM1124T','CRI5000','NON02315H','DYNJ57651','COI11492','RSH18542028','PWF51170H','MSD02016','BHL2B2543Q','DYNJAPF6030','PAIN0930A','B-D305601','MDS093948','BXT2D72N75X','MDRQWRC18363G','BMGV1921','HDIA3H0181Z','PINK2504H','B-D367283Z','SYRS101272FZ','MPH01WMLWMT5','MIK07CA109','KDL67800H','ALA48565Z','COI1759','DELIVER1','GHF3857','MDS0817617','GPK80900','BMG333855','DYNJ35212F','NPKP03672H','ALA42180Z','K-CT17X5','J-J6823A','MSC86400','DYNJSD1061','DYND50422','SDJ7989071','DYNJ904195','BRD0165L20H','FITSTRETCHU1','UTD66800405Z','ARWAB05060PK','MNT6300H','MDS809850','B-D408269Z','PMP4173','B-D373807','WOL66081LW30','MSC3066H','HTP3812','MNT1012','J-J9082Z','BMG313004','FOGCTF03','SLDBL250','ABB1265828','HTP18112','BMGL7501','DYND40702F','B-D305763Z','MDS066003Z','MDS251512LF','NON21430LFH','MDS80615T','RCC12016','MDS1247614F','BMG4894278','0409-1159-01','PRD5787004CS','HTBH7658TW','MDS9914HP','K-C79725','ORT16300S','HTP18414','MDS087006LF','HUD1166Z','KDL2022AZ','NON22660','B-D305156Z','SCS307393','MDS400EL','PM2127-18','ASOLCC016','MDSP501100','MSC7322EPH','FIT33600AZ','BXT2D72N80XZ','SQU175611','SQU411807','MSG2085','PPR021002','DYND80417','DYNJAA9500','B-D305932ZZ','MSC5100H','NON27375','W-A03100U','ASOLCC012','QTX716510','SWD270207','MDS601MDBL','DYNJAAJRS3','MSC2712H','DYND10722','MSG9065H','ASO111987','COI11473','PTX580011H','B-D405092','MENMX5030','DVT10R','FG2702','DYNJ902990B','SCS7345850','MDTVCVF184854','SWD412600H','ABB1268928','BXTAT71021','KTC627503410','MDS806570','MDS4051203','MPH01WRJRA','DYNJ904282','MSC094109','DYNJAAPI100SH','SDJ7992170','ASO150377H','MIK03KP30','PRG74897','DYNJP2411','DYNJ56767','B-D309570','MMM73003','PBE1098','MMM15341Z','MMM1296F','B-D373911','MDS88000B6','NON25501H','RSH504570','K-C34198','DRE3241482A','ADLR305222','DB230','HUD111030','BXTLTSP1500','DYNJE63654S','DYNJ904472A','ETHZ493G','WTLSB2','QTX624','MDS9913HPLRE','MPP3003U','ASH4101440','MDTS2474V4E','MDTSB8B35MUL','DYND11218','SYR101272Z','NON80328Z','BXTDJ4011XH','KDL2835Z','DYNJ41039B','BMGS80045384H','MDS9961067','BRD0043600','DYND41904','AR6592083RH','COKG32789EA','M-A58201','49281-418-50','MMM90046','CUR02279RBZ','DYNJRA0349B','CUR253590H','MDS202105','DYNJS0115','NON27200XL','ORT11100XLCS','NON23326','ALA42311CS','MDS138020','MSG2480Z','MDS138007Z','0409-2339-34','MSG2010300','DYNJ24715K','8800JTHL','DYND74020','KDL8403H','BRD53614GH','BRD154004H','DYNJP2228P','BRD123624AH','MDS3265106','DYNJ37697C','CND0035040','B-D382523','DYND11502H','MSC281226LBH','MDS30408B','HUD809337','BCC902001','ALA1439','MMM76530','DYNJ24716F','MDSM611550','MPPA504U','MLK96370H','MPHT0001','ETHJ232H','COI10881','BMG413504H','GOJ90211M','HUD510215','MSC1044Z','DYND11573H','SQU413155','MDTFALLMATG','MSC351300H','ARNES01','NON28533BZ','NON27036','BVS376984','MDSMJ361','MDS89668XW','COI1166H','AED9730SMA','BMG470191','W-A106618','QTXAD300500','MSC9748H','DYNJ56530A','MSC9866EPZ','MCKC9108M','MF545H','DYNJP2205S','MSG9660','DERTP1105','MDSP105224','SWD1540111CS','MDS601LD','MMM15342Z','BHL2B1322Q','DYND74278','ASH4001440','MDSP121010','MDS5452015F','MMO1025','BHL2N3345','KCP41083','ENT1255BH','MSC281242LB','QTX251001','EVSTOOL121P','RDPA22','USU173049H','DYNJ51813A','MDS093902','849NNTM','MSC97162EPZ','MIT6P10755','DYNJ05144','DYNJ50952C','BHL2C4040','SDJ7990870','DYND70360','VS711S','CON6112','B-D305921Z','B-D305220Z','BRD153204H','SKA759508','DYNJ54594C','ADC352','COI50462H','MDS78912Z','BMG4253523Z','HMK10008','MSC0924004H','COI15606','PCD085005','PRD5787003CSZ','NON255015','GCT31433538','DYNJ43869F','B-D305195Z','J-J801407Z','MDS1228118','AUG63500','MLK86051H','DYND60605H','MNK0005','DYND20300','DET3PHTRODWM','NON27386','DYND70800','ETH1735G','BMGL5100','KDL8938FP','PAIN0545','MDS6802','K-C47500','MSG1580Z','ETHA185H','HUD1101','DYNJ902789A','CND130309AH','KDL441107H','LTP31142980','LTP31142493Z','MDS1186301','J-J801399Z','NON6028H','MND0103042734','SCP18020','BRD042824','W-A08800U','MSG5065H','610NCCM-CM','B-D306545Z','MSC20109EPH','MDS9910HPRE','ARWAK15703HH','PMP4173H','NON270201Z','MSG2065Z','SLT49507725','RTI10131H','MMM15382HH','HUN6030622','COKG14731EA','SKA967600','MMM90203','BRD50614H','375554000RH','HCS120E','DYNJ50743A','MCD114130C','B-D377210','MSC098214','W-A68064','MDS31505B']
  unspsc_link = []
  for i in myList:
      unspsc_link.append("https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP{}".format(i))
  print(unspsc_link)
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  d = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  d.get("https://www.medline.com/")
  windows_before = d.current_window_handle
  for my_href in unspsc_link:
      try:
          d.execute_script("window.open('" + my_href +"');")
          WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
          windows_after = d.window_handles
          new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
          d.switch_to.window(new_window)
          WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#element_css")))
      except TimeoutException as e:
          print("Web Page {} not loaded. Opening next url...".format(my_href))
          d.close()
          d.switch_to.window(windows_before)
  d.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCAM000105', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS1299220', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG418021', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPFG2603', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTP18392', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI11590', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMNT416', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS3248101', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHMQ110706', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDT14WHT38TE', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSDJ7984028', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSYRS100187Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D305195', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPWSD909165', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPK-C52818', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS3230215', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS80337Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS4016104', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTP18132', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSWD773621', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPW-A3942211100', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMO2328H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPGEM2124T', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ43441A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPK-C34156', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPTX005465', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBXT2D72N85XZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJRA1022A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI10567', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPAZRPFNBF1000', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBHD766H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMRS653320Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTP18923', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMPASR315', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON27200', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPQDPM3600', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPESRK2000', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSWD431302Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSYR110235Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG473448', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDTPC4M34', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJAAHMEHEPA', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSL06545', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSYR130010Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS093944H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPGEM1124T', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCRI5000', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON02315H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ57651', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI11492', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPRSH18542028', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPWF51170H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSD02016', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBHL2B2543Q', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJAPF6030', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPAIN0930A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D305601', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS093948', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBXT2D72N75X', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDRQWRC18363G', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMGV1921', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHDIA3H0181Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPINK2504H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D367283Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSYRS101272FZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMPH01WMLWMT5', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMIK07CA109', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPKDL67800H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPALA48565Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI1759', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDELIVER1', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPGHF3857', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS0817617', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPGPK80900', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG333855', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ35212F', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNPKP03672H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPALA42180Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPK-CT17X5', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPJ-J6823A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC86400', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJSD1061', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND50422', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSDJ7989071', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ904195', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBRD0165L20H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPFITSTRETCHU1', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPUTD66800405Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPARWAB05060PK', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMNT6300H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS809850', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D408269Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPMP4173', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D373807', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPWOL66081LW30', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC3066H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTP3812', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMNT1012', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPJ-J9082Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG313004', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPFOGCTF03', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSLDBL250', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPABB1265828', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTP18112', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMGL7501', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND40702F', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D305763Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS066003Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS251512LF', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON21430LFH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS80615T', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPRCC12016', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS1247614F', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG4894278', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP0409-1159-01', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPRD5787004CS', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTBH7658TW', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS9914HP', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPK-C79725', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPORT16300S', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTP18414', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS087006LF', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHUD1166Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPKDL2022AZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON22660', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D305156Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSCS307393', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS400EL', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPM2127-18', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPASOLCC016', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDSP501100', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC7322EPH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPFIT33600AZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBXT2D72N80XZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSQU175611', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSQU411807', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSG2085', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPPR021002', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND80417', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJAA9500', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D305932ZZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC5100H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON27375', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPW-A03100U', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPASOLCC012', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPQTX716510', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSWD270207', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS601MDBL', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJAAJRS3', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC2712H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND10722', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSG9065H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPASO111987', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI11473', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPTX580011H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D405092', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMENMX5030', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDVT10R', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPFG2702', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ902990B', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSCS7345850', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDTVCVF184854', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSWD412600H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPABB1268928', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBXTAT71021', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPKTC627503410', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS806570', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS4051203', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMPH01WRJRA', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ904282', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC094109', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJAAPI100SH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSDJ7992170', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPASO150377H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMIK03KP30', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPRG74897', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJP2411', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ56767', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D309570', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMM73003', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPBE1098', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMM15341Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMM1296F', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D373911', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS88000B6', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON25501H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPRSH504570', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPK-C34198', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDRE3241482A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPADLR305222', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDB230', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHUD111030', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBXTLTSP1500', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJE63654S', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ904472A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPETHZ493G', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPWTLSB2', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPQTX624', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS9913HPLRE', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMPP3003U', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPASH4101440', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDTS2474V4E', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDTSB8B35MUL', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND11218', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSYR101272Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON80328Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBXTDJ4011XH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPKDL2835Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ41039B', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMGS80045384H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS9961067', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBRD0043600', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND41904', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPAR6592083RH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOKG32789EA', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPM-A58201', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP49281-418-50', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMM90046', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCUR02279RBZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJRA0349B', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCUR253590H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS202105', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJS0115', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON27200XL', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPORT11100XLCS', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON23326', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPALA42311CS', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS138020', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSG2480Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS138007Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP0409-2339-34', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSG2010300', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ24715K', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP8800JTHL', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND74020', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPKDL8403H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBRD53614GH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBRD154004H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJP2228P', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBRD123624AH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS3265106', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ37697C', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCND0035040', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D382523', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND11502H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC281226LBH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS30408B', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHUD809337', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBCC902001', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPALA1439', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMM76530', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ24716F', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDSM611550', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMPPA504U', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMLK96370H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMPHT0001', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPETHJ232H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI10881', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG413504H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPGOJ90211M', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHUD510215', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC1044Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND11573H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSQU413155', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDTFALLMATG', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC351300H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPARNES01', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON28533BZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON27036', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBVS376984', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDSMJ361', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS89668XW', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI1166H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPAED9730SMA', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG470191', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPW-A106618', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPQTXAD300500', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC9748H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ56530A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC9866EPZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMCKC9108M', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMF545H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJP2205S', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSG9660', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDERTP1105', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDSP105224', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSWD1540111CS', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS601LD', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMM15342Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBHL2B1322Q', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND74278', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPASH4001440', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDSP121010', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS5452015F', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMO1025', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBHL2N3345', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPKCP41083', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPENT1255BH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC281242LB', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPQTX251001', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPEVSTOOL121P', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPRDPA22', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPUSU173049H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ51813A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS093902', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP849NNTM', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC97162EPZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMIT6P10755', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ05144', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ50952C', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBHL2C4040', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSDJ7990870', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND70360', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPVS711S', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCON6112', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D305921Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D305220Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBRD153204H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSKA759508', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ54594C', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPADC352', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI50462H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS78912Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG4253523Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHMK10008', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC0924004H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI15606', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPCD085005', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPRD5787003CSZ', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON255015', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPGCT31433538', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ43869F', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D305195Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPJ-J801407Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS1228118', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPAUG63500', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMLK86051H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND60605H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMNK0005', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND20300', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDET3PHTRODWM', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON27386', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYND70800', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPETH1735G', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMGL5100', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPKDL8938FP', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPAIN0545', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS6802', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPK-C47500', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSG1580Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPETHA185H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHUD1101', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ902789A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCND130309AH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPKDL441107H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPLTP31142980', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPLTP31142493Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS1186301', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPJ-J801399Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON6028H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMND0103042734', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSCP18020', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBRD042824', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPW-A08800U', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSG5065H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP610NCCM-CM', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D306545Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC20109EPH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS9910HPRE', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPARWAK15703HH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPMP4173H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON270201Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSG2065Z', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSLT49507725', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPRTI10131H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMM15382HH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHUN6030622', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOKG14731EA', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSKA967600', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMM90203', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBRD50614H', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP375554000RH', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHCS120E', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ50743A', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMCD114130C', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D377210', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSC098214', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPW-A68064', 'https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS31505B']
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCAM000105 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS1299220 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG418021 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPFG2603 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTP18392 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI11590 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMNT416 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS3248101 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHMQ110706 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDT14WHT38TE not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSDJ7984028 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSYRS100187Z not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPB-D305195 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPWSD909165 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPK-C52818 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS3230215 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS80337Z not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS4016104 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTP18132 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSWD773621 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPW-A3942211100 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMMO2328H not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPGEM2124T not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJ43441A not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPK-C34156 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPTX005465 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBXT2D72N85XZ not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJRA1022A not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPCOI10567 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPAZRPFNBF1000 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBHD766H not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMRS653320Z not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPHTP18923 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMPASR315 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPNON27200 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPPQDPM3600 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPESRK2000 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSWD431302Z not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPSYR110235Z not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPBMG473448 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDTPC4M34 not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPDYNJAAHMEHEPA not loaded. Opening next url...
  Web Page https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMSL06545 not loaded. Opening next url...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom exception, and run your code in  try block. This way you can maintain execution of program even if error arise.

Comment: 1. Create exception, here you have tutorial : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception

Comment: In case of exception you can add wrong values to array and do whatever you want with them. Sorry for not writing code but I’m on my phone and in other country than my computer

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from line with unspsc_line= []. I just add try: and except Exception: pass  It will pass any errors.

```
unspsc_link = []
for i in myList:
    try:
        unspsc_link.append("https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP" + i)
    except Exception:
        pass
d.get('https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS705312')
for my_href in unspsc_link:
    try:
        windows_before  = d.current_window_handle
        d.execute_script("window.open('" + my_href +"');")
        WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
        windows_after = d.window_handles
        new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
        d.switch_to.window(new_window)
        time.sleep(3)
        print(d.title)
        d.close()
        d.switch_to.window(windows_before)
    except Exception:
        my_href.remove(i)
```

Comment: i want to delete that number from the  mylist so that new number and link should be generated and pass in my herf

Comment: hey @S__ it open the same page every time

Comment: It is so hard to understand what you want. You can try updated answer. I not sure why you open here page d.get('https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDPMDS705312') and after this use js to open new windows. If you want to try to open few times add for _ in range(fewtimes) in you cicle and break before "except"